# PDOException could not find driver using XAMPP laravel project and postgresql on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, laravel, xampp

Getting `"[PDOException] could not find driver"` error. I am trying to migrate using `$php` artisan migrate

I have tried this as a fix 
http://www.shaneperera.com/blog/postgres-app-fix-could-not-find-driver-issue/
and 
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/what-is-sip-in-osx-10-11-el-capitan/
to fix the `"/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/#INST@17000#:` Operation not permitted" error. Still got the same error message.

Comment: Please add your code so we can look at problems

Comment: What code exactly do you need? I'm trying to set-up a laravel project to have a postgresql database.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this using [postgresql driver set-up](https://gist.github.com/giorgiofellipe/6282df335fd310de4108) Instructions

Note that the php.ini to add the extensions in is the one in the '/etc/php.ini' location for Mac OS X El Capitan. If it does not exist, cp the existing 'php.ini.default' to 'php.ini' and add the new extensions according to the instructions on the link. Use sudo nano to avoid permission errors.